# Unintended button click behavior.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

When clicking into button #1, button #2 appears and button #2 is receiving a click event right after button #1 is clicked.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary default-btn" type="button">Ver no mapa</button> 

<button class="btn btn-primary button-maps display-none" type="button">
   <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/1HEDVJ2QHYr" target="_blank">
     <div class="btn-img-container">
      <img src="/unidades/PublishingImages/home-itaim/maps-icon.png" height="22" 
      width="22" alt="">
     </div>  
   </a> 
   <div class="divisor">
   </div>
   <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/1HEDVJ2QHYr" target="_blank">
     <div class="btn-img-container"> 
       <img src="/unidades/PublishingImages/home-itaim/waze-icon.png" 
       height="22" width="22" alt="">
      </div> 
    </a>
</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".default-btn").on("click touchstart", function(){
    $(this).addClass("display-none");
    $(this).parent().children(".button-maps").removeClass("display-none");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:-

You were clicking with the wrong way.

We can click on `.default-btn` class with this way

```
('body').on("click", ".default-btn", function(){});
```

Now we have selected `.default-btn` class which is found inside `body` tag then run function.

```js
  $("body").on("click", ".default-btn", function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().children(".button-maps").removeClass("display-none");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<button class="btn btn-primary default-btn" type="button">Ver no mapa</button> 

<button class="btn btn-primary button-maps display-none" type="button">
   <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/1HEDVJ2QHYr" target="_blank">
     <div class="btn-img-container">
      <img src="/unidades/PublishingImages/home-itaim/maps-icon.png" height="22" 
      width="22" alt="">
     </div>  
   </a> 
   <div class="divisor">
   </div>
   <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/1HEDVJ2QHYr" target="_blank">
     <div class="btn-img-container"> 
       <img src="/unidades/PublishingImages/home-itaim/waze-icon.png" 
       height="22" width="22" alt="">
      </div> 
    </a>
</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, it worked! Could you explain me what was going on?

Comment: @Arthur Muller Welcome & i edit my answer with explain.